# 14.04: How to use NVIDIA Graphics instead of Intel integrated graphics?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I previously tried to install my nvidia graphics card driver more than 50 times when this version was released (14.04) and every time i always got either blank screen, terminal only with no x-server or it would go back to the first alternative driver there was when it was installed.

This was the only reason why i stopped using linux (ubuntu). now im trying to give it another try but i need real detailed help and guidance. I have tried many ways and techniques from forums here and the result was never great.

**My PC (laptop)

- Intel i5 4200/intel hd integrated video graphics
- 8gb ram
- 500gb hdd**
- **nvidia geforce 720m**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Comment: This isn't a true answer to your question, hence why I'm putting it here, but I highly recommend giving Linux Mint a try instead of Ubuntu.  It was my gateway Linux distro, and it's Nvidia driver support blows Ubuntu's out of the water.  Plus it's very similar under the hood (it uses the same Command Line instructions - apt-get upgrade, etc, and installs the same deb files).  Nvidia support for laptops in Ubuntu is still making me sad.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this may just be linking you to another page of instructions, but this one worked perfectly for me and I keep it bookmarked as a fallback:

http://mylinuxexplore.blogspot.com/2014/03/solved-nvidia-cant-access-secondary-gpu.html?m=1

I am running on a Lenovo Y50 with an Intel i7 / Geforce GTX 860M and for whatever reason I can only get the nvidia-331-updates drivers to work as this link suggests. Literally any other nvidia driver will leave me with the same problem you are describing. It seems like its hit or miss with this Optimus technology. Hopefully we will get a good update for it in the near future.

Answer (score -1):

If you can not start X server go into a tty terminal (CTL+ALT+F2)
Update :
    `sudo apt-get update` and make sure that x server is installed `sudo dpkg -l | grep xserver`
There are 2 approaches to installing the Nvidia graphics driver(s).

1. Install them with the apt package manager  `apt-cache search nvidia`
   You should then see a list of available drivers to choose from. Run: `apt-get install nvidia 3XX`
   You may also need to install 'libgl' as well as the nvidia settings:`apt-cache search nvidia-settings`
2. Download the [proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) for your respective GPU (you may need to add Nvidia to the apt/sources.list). Then run the install script (the install script may add Nvidia to the apt/sources.list file)
   Then, reboot.